# Using the NET framework in a Unity script

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

In order to move my player immediately at constant speed, I wanted to change the user's joystick input like that:

```
float fH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
fH = Math.Sign(fH);

transform.position += transform.right * fH * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Now Unity tells me that the name "Math" does not exist in the current context.

I never expected that I would have to write something like "using Math" (untested).

This made me think if I should use any NET framework class at all or just use Unity's built-in functions.

Is there a reason NOT to use the NET framework in a Unity script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to either add `using System;` or use `System.Math.Sign(fH);` - No, there is no reason you cannot use these in Unity.

However, given that you are using Unity, you might be intested in using [`Mathf`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.html) instead. The build in `Math` class from .NET works with double, while `Mathf` is optimized to work with float. That means you would use [`Mathf.Sign`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html). **Errata**: Reading the documentation on `Mathf.Sign`, it appears it will return 1 when the input is 0.

Comment: You're right. Mathf wouldn't work, but using System; and Math.Sign does.